# MySQL Stored Procedure running slow in PhpMyAdmin but fast in Workbench

Tags: mysql

I have created a stored procedure in MySQL which calls a view to fetch results.

I have executed the stored procedure in MySQL Workbench and its executing in 5 secs.

However, when I run the same in phpMyAdmin it takes 50 seconds.

I have researched and founded that collation of the table columns takes time for that i used the Convert() method on the column but didnt work.

Can anyone help?

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE `inspection_transactions` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `point_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `inspection_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `instruction_pool_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `inspection_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inspection_company_transaction_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `inspection_type` int DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1:Single, 2:Company, 3:Home '
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

** View **

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `hms`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `testingdump`.`inspection_transactions_company_number_grouped_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`point_id` AS `point_id`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`point_name` AS `point_name`,
        MONTH(`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_date`) AS `month`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_date` AS `inspection_date`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_id` AS `inspection_id`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`instruction_pool_id` AS `instruction_pool_id`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_company_transaction_id` AS `inspection_company_transaction_id`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`customer_id` AS `customer_id`,
        CONCAT(SUBSTR(`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`instruction_pool_name`,
                    1,
                    3),
                ' ',
                SUM(`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`result`)) AS `result_concat`,
        SUM(`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`result`) AS `result`,
        `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`instruction_pool_name` AS `instruction_pool_name`
    FROM
        `testingdump`.`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`
    GROUP BY `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`point_id` , `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`instruction_pool_id` , MONTH(`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_date`) , `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_company_transaction_id`
    ORDER BY `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`point_id` , `inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`instruction_pool_id` , MONTH(`inspection_transactions_company_number_view`.`inspection_date`);
```

** Stored Procedure **

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`hms`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `company_transactions_number_monthly_pivot`(IN cus_id INT, IN insp_id INT, IN start_date datetime, IN end_date datetime)
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl1 AS
(   SELECT point_id,point_name, instruction_pool_id, instruction_pool_name, month, convert(result using utf8) collate utf8_general_ci
    FROM `inspection_transactions_company_number_grouped_view`
    WHERE `customer_id` = cus_id AND `inspection_id` = insp_id and `inspection_date` > start_date and `inspection_date` < end_date  
);


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT point_name, ', @sql, ' FROM tbl1 GROUP BY point_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Maybe Workbench doesn't fetch every row immediately but fetches remaining rows as you scroll.

Comment: Any way to optimize it in phpMyadmin?